# Is it possible to have a global rating in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, review, ratings

Is it possible to have a global rating in Magento 2 instead of have stars for Price, Value, Quality individually?

Maybe creating a new "Global" rating called just "Rating"?

That will be the correct way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think of Creating a new "Global" rating called just "Rating", is not the bad idea. This is a very good and logical idea.

But you have to disable other rating `Price, Value, Quality`

Comment: Hi @AmitBera that is exactly what I've done.